# Android App (not on playstore) existing users APK update - new libraries

Tags: android, react-native, release, release-management

I've an existing REACT app (android only) that's been installed by ~200 users. This app is not on playstore for legal reasons. I've been pushing JS bundle changes via code push but we've finally reached a point where we need to include new libraries in our app. (facebook login for example)

If there a new library to be installed even for updating, I believe we will have to ask existing users to re-download or maintain the two versions eternally. Is there a better way of solving this so all my users, new and existing can be on the same branch ?

Comment: I think you need to ask them to download and install the new version. You can simply notify them to install the new version and explain how they can do it and tell them that the older one won't be maintained by some date you set. I am not aware of any other solution for this since your app was downloaded locally and installed like that and not by any other service.

Comment: Yeah, we managed to think ahead and include codepush but that only updates the JSBundle and this was somehow missed.